# How to minimize number of operations in multiplication of a binary matrix by a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be a space where the operators $+$ and $-$ are defined (just to give some context, in my specific case, elements of $\mathbb{D}$ are very large matrices with homogenous dimensions).

Let $A$ be a binary matrix of size $(n,m)$ and $b$ a vector of elements in $\mathbb{D}$ of size $m$.

Let $y=Ab$ be the matrix product of $A$ and $b$.

For example

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0 \\
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
y_4 \\
y_5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_0 \\
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3 \\
b_4 \\
b_5 \\
b_6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_0 + b_1 + b_3 \\
b_0 + b_1 + b_2 \\
b_0 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \\
b_2 + b_3  \\
b_0 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 \\
b_0 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 + b_6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If we use a brute force approach, the number of additions required to obtain the results is the number of ones in the matrix $A$ minus the number of rows. In the example, there are $25-6=19$ additions.

By introducing a few temporary variables $z_i$, we could transform the calculation in the example above as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_0&=b_0+b_1 \\
z_1&=b_2+b_3 \\
z_2&=z_0+z_1 \\
z_3&=z_2+b_4+b_5 \\
y_0 &= z_0 + b_3 \\
y_1 &= z_0 + b_2 \\
y_2 &= z_2 \\
y_3 &= z_1\\
y_4 &= z_3\\
y_5 &= z_3 + b_6\\
\end{aligned}
$$
which reduce the number of additions to 8.

I would like to devise an algorithm which generates a computation plan to minimize the number of additions, via opportunistically introducing temporary variables. Subtractions might also be allowed and have the same cost as additions.

Comment: Optimization of matrix multiplication is a [deep subject.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication)

Comment: Are subtractions allowed as well?

Comment: Yes, subtractions are allowed.